# target_link_libraries error with header only files and static library

Tags: cmake

In my project I have a folder containing 3 subdirectories. 2 of the 3 directories contain header only files while the 3rd directory has a static library. To be clear flow is as follows:

I have written CMake lists for folder1 and 2 and overall CMake for MainFolder. As I run the project I get an error stating:
**Cannot specify link libraries for target which is not built
  by this project**

My Cmake File is as follows:

1)Individual CMakeLists.txt for Folder 1 and Folder2 contain

```
    add_library(mylib INTERFACE)
    target_sources(mylib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mylib.h)
    target_link_libraries(mylib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

2)Overall CMakeLists.txt for MainFolder contains

```
    target_link_libraries( lib1 lib2 Folder3/lib3)
```

Comment: Are you linking the header only libs to the static library? Or the other way around? You should also probably post more cmake code that's more indicative of the issue. Note that you call with `target_link_libraries(lib1 lib2 Folder3/lib3)` is linking lib2 and "Folder3/lib3" to lib1.

Comment: So to give some background this whole folder is a third party folder which I am trying to integrate in my project. The static library (Folder3) is actually the source code and other two folders contain header only files(Folder 1 and Folder2).

Comment: It seems the error is about line `target_link_libraries(mylib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})` and I wonder what do you want to achieve by that line.

Comment: @mounika I think one thing you might be misunderstanding is that you cannot specify dependencies/linkages between *folders*. Instead you must do this via *targets*. It would be helpful if you could post most if not all of your cmake code along with the full directory structure of your project so I can give a more complete answer.